Pricing the embedded option of a Zero-Coupon Linear Callable Note
I'm having a lot of trouble trying to price the embedded option within a zero-coupon linear callable note. The note details are as follows:
Issuer: Citigroup, First Settle Date (07/05/2024), Maturity (07/05/2029)
Coupon (Accrued and paid as lump sum at call date or maturity): 5.75%
Call schedule:
7/5/25 at 105.75%
7/5/26 at 111.5%
7/5/27 at 117.25%
7/5/28 at 123.00%
Using Bloomberg OAS and YAS doesn't seem to yield the correct results as the option price is a bit low.
I just started trying to use QuantLib to price the option and have modified the code from another question on the forum for my purposes, but the OAS returned is negative and not sure how to return the option price by itself as well. I've included the code below. Any help is greatly appreciated
Note: The zero curve is taken from the BVAL STRIPS curve
import QuantLib as ql
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


bf = ql.BondFunctions
qd = ql.DateParser.parseFormatted

# Conventions
accrual_convention = ql.Unadjusted
Rule = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
endofMonth = False
firstDate = None

#OAS
compounding = ql.Simple
frequency = ql.Once

calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE)

a = 0.03
sigma = 0.27
grid_points = 100
face_amount = 100
mkt_price = 100

contract = {
    'IssueDate': ql.Date(3,7,2024), 
    'MaturityDate': ql.Date(5,7,2029),
    'SettlementDays': 2,
    'RealValue': 0.0575,
    'FirstCallDate': ql.Date(5,7,2025),
    'OptionalityEndDate': ql.Date(5,7,2029),
    'OperatingCountry': 'US',
    'StrikeDate': [ql.Date(5,7,2025), ql.Date(5, 7,2026), ql.Date(5,7,2027), ql.Date(5,7,2028), ql.Date(5,7,2029)],
    'OptionalityType': ['Call', 'Call', 'Call', 'Call', 'Call'],
    'NoticeDays': [5, 5, 5, 5],
    'StrikePrice': [105.75, 111.5, 117.25, 123, 128.75]}

# Here is the zero curve:

times= np.array([ '0 MO', '3 MO', '6 MO', '1 YR', '2 YR', '3 YR',
       '5 YR', '7 YR', '10 YR', '20 YR', '30 YR'], dtype=object)

dates = [
         ql.Date(17,7, 2024), ql.Date(17,10,2024),ql.Date(17,1,2025), ql.Date(17,7,2025),
         ql.Date(17,7,2026),ql.Date(17,7,2027), ql.Date(17,7,2029),
         ql.Date(17,7,2031), ql.Date(17,7,2034),ql.Date(17,7,2044),
         ql.Date(17,7,2054)]

rates = np.array([ 0.0533, 0.05699 , 0.05630 ,
                   0.05395  , 0.04865  , 0.04638 , 0.04528 , 0.04615  ,
                   0.04796  , 0.05055 , 0.04951 ])

day_count = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISDA)
calc_date = ql.Date(16,7,2024)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calc_date

issue_date = contract["IssueDate"]
maturity_date = contract["MaturityDate"]
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Annual)

coupon = contract["RealValue"]
settlement_days = contract["SettlementDays"]

# Determine Schedule
schedule = ql.Schedule(issue_date,
                       maturity_date,
                       tenor,
                       calendar,
                       accrual_convention,
                       accrual_convention,
                       Rule,
                       endofMonth)

# Initiate Zero Curve
curve = ql.ZeroCurve(dates,
                     rates,
                     ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISDA),
                     calendar,
                     ql.Linear())
curve.enableExtrapolation()
ts_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(curve)

def get_call_schedule(df, period=ql.Period(ql.Annual)):
    dates = df["StrikeDate"]
    prices = df["StrikePrice"]
    callability_schedule = ql.CallabilitySchedule()
    null_calendar = ql.NullCalendar()
    call_date = df["StrikeDate"][0]
    for time in range(len(df["StrikeDate"])):
        callability_price  = ql.BondPrice(prices[time],
                                                 ql.BondPrice.Clean)
        callability_schedule.append(ql.Callability(callability_price, 
                                                   ql.Callability.Call,
                                                   dates[time]))
        call_date = null_calendar.advance(call_date, period)
    return callability_schedule


callability_schedule = get_call_schedule(contract)

bond = ql.CallableFixedRateBond(settlement_days,
                                face_amount,
                                schedule,
                                [coupon],
                                day_count,
                                ql.Following,
                                face_amount,
                                calc_date,
                                callability_schedule)



def value_bond(a, s, ts_handle, grid_points, bond):
    model = ql.HullWhite(ts_handle, a, s)
    engine = ql.TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine(model, grid_points)
    bond.setPricingEngine(engine)
    return bond

bondprice = value_bond(a, sigma, ts_handle, grid_points, bond)
OAS = bondprice.OAS(mkt_price,
                    ts_handle,
                    day_count, compounding, frequency)
bond_yield = bondprice.bondYield(mkt_price,
                                 day_count,
                                 compounding, 
                                 frequency)
                                 

print(OAS)
print(bond_yield)
print(bondprice)

Tried to find the OAS of the callable note but returned a negative number. I'd like to find the Option price, expected call date based on an interest rate model, and the OAS as well.
